# Can I return the relationship as a field within a node?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I currently have this query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[r:CHILD_OF]-(t1:Thing)<-[:TAGGED]-(post:Post)
```

and later on I have

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (this)<-[:TAGGED]-(post:Post)
```

and because they all return together (as a list of posts), I don't know which posts were children of a thing or which ones just tagged "this" directly.

Is it possible to return when "r" which is the name of the "CHILD_OF" relationship variable here is present?

Full post looks something like this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (this)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(t1:Thing)<-[:TAGGED]-(post:Post)
WITH COLLECT(post) as rows, this
OPTIONAL MATCH (this)<-[:TAGGED]-(p:Post)
WITH rows + COLLECT(p) as allRows
UNWIND allRows as post
RETURN DISTINCT post
ORDER BY post.date DESC
```

I don't want it as a map as neo4j-graphql-js doesn't support that, they exclusively support returning single nodes. So I also can't do return post, r

```
type Thing {
    id: ID!,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    image: String,
    followers: [User] @relation(name: "FOLLOWS", direction: "IN"),
    posts: [Post] @cypher(statement: """
        OPTIONAL MATCH (this)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(t1:Thing)<-[:TAGGED]-(post:Post)
        WITH COLLECT(post) as rows, this
        OPTIONAL MATCH (this)<-[:TAGGED]-(p:Post)
        WITH rows + COLLECT(p) as allRows
        UNWIND allRows as post
        RETURN DISTINCT post
        ORDER BY post.date DESC
    """)
   
}

type User {
    id: ID!,
    uid: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    bio: String,
    followers: [User] @relation(name: "FOLLOWS", direction: "OUT"),
    post_count: Int @cypher(statement: """
        MATCH (this)-[:WROTE]->(p:Post)
        RETURN count(p)
    """),
    homepage_posts: [Post] @cypher(statement: """
        OPTIONAL MATCH (this)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(something)-[:WROTE|TAGGED]-(post:Post)        
        WITH COLLECT(post) as rows
        OPTIONAL MATCH (this)-[:WROTE]->(post:Post)
        WITH rows + COLLECT(post) as allRows
        UNWIND allRows as post
        RETURN DISTINCT post
        ORDER BY post.date DESC
    """)
}

type Relationship {
    type: String
}

type Post {
    id: ID!,
    body: String,
    images: [String],
    date: DateTime,
    isRetweet: Boolean,
    rating: Float,
    relationship: Relationship,
    author: User @relation(name: "WROTE", direction: "IN"),
    things: [Thing] @relation(name: "TAGGED", direction: "OUT"),
    likes: [User] @cypher(statement: """
        MATCH (u:User)-[r:LIKES]->(this)
        RETURN u
    """),
}
```

Comment: Neo4j-graphql-js supports map? You will need to define a custom type though probably

Comment: I don’t think you can return a map, nei4j-graphql-js expects a node back, no? Do i have that wrong?

Comment: The main query needs a node if you want to use "this" in subqueries. You can return a map in subqueries if its return is of a type that doesn't have any subqueries. So the main reason you want a node is because of subqueries, orherwise you can return a map

Comment: Hi Tomas - I’m confused what that might look like? When I tried to return a map it didn’t work. Also when I tried to use a virtual node it worked in the Browser but not in neo4j-graphql-js.

Comment: I can't seem to return the node and its relationship in a way that neo4j-graphql-js will accept, does it need to be a node? Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post full types definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227547/discussion-between-dan-fein-and-tomaz-bratanic).

Comment: And yep! I posted a sample of the types, think that covers where I'm at currently. The homepage_posts under User is where I'd like it to return the relationship currently denoted by variable "r" so I can see if that post is returned because the user follows that "something"